# Understanding a Set of Formulas that Adjusts a Sequence of Numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, statistics

I am working through the equations below. They are expected to change a sequence so that the first n - m numbers are 0 and numbers m - n + 1 to n are changed such that the total of this new sequence is the same as the total of the sequence before the equations below are applied.

I must not be following the equations correctly because I end up with a sequence which has a total different from the total in the original sequence. Is someone able to help me and tell me what the new sequence should be? Also, I have noted below that I think one of the formulas I was provided has a mistake, I wonder if anyone else agrees.

Many thanks in advance.

Assume the following:

$$F_1^*,…,F_n^*$$

We use the following equations that ensure there are only m numbers in the new sequence that are greater than 0, where m < n.

$$F_{i,j}^*=\frac{F_j^*}{m};i=1,….n;j=1,….m $$
[I believe the above equation should read: $F_{i,j}^*=\frac{F_i^*}{m};i=1,….n;j=1,….m $] Does anyone else agree?

We relabel $$F_{(i-1)*m+j}^+=F_{i,j}^*$$ and set

$$F_j^*=0;j=1,…,n-m$$ and

$$F_j=\sum_{i=(j-1)*n+1}^{j*n} = F_i^* ; j=n-m+1,…, n$$

The inputs we have been provided are:

$$F_1^*=10$$
$$F_2^*=8$$
$$F_3^*=5$$
$$F_4^*=2$$
$$Total=25$$

$$m=3$$
$$n=4$$